# Ошибка при запуске кода Python

Tags: python, tkinter

Давно не писал код на пайтоне, решил написать спам машину с UI, но проблема в том, что я не могу задать количество сообщений, из-за того что не могу преобразовать str в int, как просит сама выдающаяся ошибка, подскажите пожалуйста как сделать.

```
import pyautogui
from time import sleep
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def spamming():
    for _ in range(kolvoinput.get()):
        pyautogui.write(titletxtp)
        pyautogui.press('Enter')



root['bg'] = '#fafafa'
root.title('Spam Machine')
root.wm_attributes('-alpha', 0.7)
root.geometry('300x250')

root.resizable(width=False, height= False)

canvas = Canvas(root, height=300, width=250)
canvas.pack()


frame = Frame(root, bg='white')
frame.place(relx=0.15, rely=0.15, relwidth=0.7, relheight=0.7)

titlekolvo = Label(frame, text='Количество сообщений')
titlekolvo.pack()

kolvoinput = Entry(frame, bg='white')
kolvoinput.pack()


titletxt = Label(frame, text='Текст')
titletxt.pack()

titletxtp = Entry(frame, bg='white')
titletxtp.pack()

btn = Button(frame, text='Готово', bg='gray', command = spamming)
btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHcnw.jpg

Comment: `range(int(kolvoinput.get()))`

Comment: Выдаётся другая ошибка

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/VsUz960

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте этот код, вы должны также вызвать `get()` для `titletxtp`

```
def spamming():
    for _ in range(int(kolvoinput.get())+1):
        pyautogui.write(titletxtp.get())
        pyautogui.press('Enter')
```

Comment: Спасибо, благодарю :) Помогло